# Javascript Date from string giving different output from Chrome to Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, date

I'm trying to write some javascript code to format a date as I want, but I have troubles making it work on Firefox (it's working as I want on Chrome).

The input I have in a form is `05/01/13` (mm/dd/yy) and I want `2013-05-01` (yyyy/mm/dd).

For that, what I did is something like this :

```
var formDate = document.getElementById("start").value;
var myDate = new Date(formDate);
var startDate = new Date();

startDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + 1);
startDate.setFullYear(myDate.getFullYear());
var FormattedDate = startDate.getFullYear() + "-" + ((startDate.getMonth() <= 10) ? "0" : "") + startDate.getMonth() + "-01"; // the day is always 01

alert(FormattedDate);
```

You can try it on both browsers here : http://jsfiddle.net/j4BLH/

On Google Chrome, this code gives me for example `2013-05-01` for May, but on Firefox, I have `1913-05-01`.

I know I could've written something like `"20" + startDate.getYear()` but I was wondering why the results were different from Chrome to Firefox ? And maybe if you have a better way of writing the code I pasted here, please let me know :)

Thanks !

Comment: Check out this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681534/why-does-javascript-evaluate-a-2-digit-year-of-00-as-1900-instead-of-2000

Comment: Seems like firefox is doing something weird, as the date is stored internally in milliseconds since epoch (1970). So, it should never return 1913. [(ECMAScript Reference)](http://objjob.phrogz.net/js/object/224)

Comment: @SpAm thanks for the link, but it doesn't really explains why Chrome & Firefox have different behaviours on this.

Comment: Date parsing is JavaScript implementation dependent and I assume that Firefox just doesn't understand the `mm/dd/yy` format - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse

Comment: if i give 2013 it is returning 2013

Comment: until 99 it is adding 1900 .Greater than 100 it is giving the same value.Very interesting

Comment: see here http://www.jr.pl/www.quirksmode.org/js/datecompat.html it may helpful to you

Comment: Use http://momentjs.com/ maybe. The cross-browser issues with dates are really painful to deal with.

Comment: @andyb thanks for the link, this would explain the why.

Comment: @DarkCthulhu thanks too, I'll have a look at this lib !

Comment: @DarkCthulhu I tried to implement the moment.js library, and on Firefox, I have the same behaviour, 13 giving 1913.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf):

> However, the expression Date.parse(x.toLocaleString()) is not required
>   to produce the same Number value as the preceding three expressions
>   and, in general, the value produced by Date.parse is
>   implementation-dependent when given any String value that does not
>   conform to the Date Time String Format (15.9.1.15) and that could not
>   be produced in that implementation by the toString or toUTCString
>   method.

When creating a date object by passing a date string to the constructor, the method of parsing is exactly the same as Date.parse.

Your date format, using a 2 digit year, is not conforming to the standard. As such, it would seem that the way these dates are parsed is implementation specific, meaning that it depends upon the Javascript engine being used. In Google's case, it's usually V8, and in Firefox, it's TraceMonkey or Rhino I believe.

In short, you should really use 4 digit years, as there is no YY in the JS standard.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this summarizes well what have been said in the comments !